# Iterate through parent elements containing specific descendent node

Tags: jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors

I would like to iterate only through parent elements that contain a specific element as descendant node.

For example:

```
<div class="field">
   <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="field">
   <input type="button" />
</div>
<div class="field">
   <input type="text" />
</div>
```

I know that using xpath, it could be accomplished by using `div[@class = 'field' and input[@type = 'text']]`

With jQuery, I would like to use something similar to `div.field[input[type = 'text']]`.

The nearest option that I know is `div.field > input[type = 'text']`, but this way I would be iterating through inputs instead of divs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `:has()` pseudo-selector:

```
$('.field:has(.text)')
```

Since it's a non-standard selector, it'll be slow compared to regular selectors, so keep that in mind if you're iterating over a ton of elements.

Comment: Regarding performance, `has` method is faster than `has` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .parents()

```
$('input[type=text]').parents('.field').each(function(){
//do your stuff
})
```

example - http://jsfiddle.net/dYKRz/